# Splitting a string into multiple strings with multiple delimiters without removing?

Tags: c++, regex, string, vector, split

I use boost framework, so it could be helpful, but I haven't found a necessary function.

For usual fast splitting I can use:

```
string str = ...;
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs, str, boost::is_any_of("mM"));
```

but it removes m and M characters.

I also can't siply use regexp because it searches the string for the longest value which meets a defined pattern.

P.S. There are a lot of similar questions, but they describe this implementation in other programming languages only.

Comment: So, you want to split on an `m `or `M` but keep that character?

Comment: Specification of splitting becomes blurry if you want your delimiters to be part of the strings, could you give an example of possible input and what you'd like to get as output?

Comment: So would `m`(/`M`) be the last character in the first string, or the first character in the second string?

Comment: m/M will join to the next substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is the following (but it is not universal and looks like too complex).

I choose one character which couldn't appear in this string. In my case it is '|'.

```
string str = ...;
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs, str, boost::is_any_of("m"));
str = boost::join(strs, "|m");
boost::split(strs, str, boost::is_any_of("M"));
str = boost::join(strs, "|M");
if (boost::iequals(str.substr(0, 1), "|") {

    str = str.substr(1);
}
boost::split(strs, str, boost::is_any_of("|"));
```

I add "|" before each of symbols m/M, except of the very first position in string. Then I split the string into substrings with deleting of this extra character

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but rather than using `vector<string>`, you could try a `vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>>` (so you get a pair of iterators to the main string for each token. Then iterate from (start of range -1 [as long as start of range is not `begin()` of main string], to end of range)

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main(void)
{
  std::string str = "FooMBarMSFM";

  std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>> tokens;

  boost::split(tokens, str, boost::is_any_of("mM"));

  for(auto r : tokens)
  {
    std::string b(r.begin(), r.end());
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    if (r.begin() != str.begin())
    {
      std::string bm(std::prev(r.begin()), r.end());
      std::cout << "With token: [" << bm << "]" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need is beyond the conception of `split`. If you want to keep 'm or M', you could write a special split by `strstr`, `strchr`,`strtok` or `find` function. You could change some code to produce a flexible `split` function.
Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void split(char *src, const char *separator, char **dest, int *num)
{
    char *pNext;
    int count = 0;

    if (src == NULL || strlen(src) == 0) return;
    if (separator == NULL || strlen(separator) == 0) return; 

    pNext = strtok(src,separator);

    while(pNext != NULL)
    {
        *dest++ = pNext;
        ++count;
        pNext = strtok(NULL,separator);
    }

    *num = count;
}
```

Besides, you could try `boost::regex`.